# Checking for Firebase uID then routing

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

So my main.dart looking like this, I just want to check if the user already loggedIn or not. If true then route him directly to Homescreen and passing the UID else to the SignIn screen.

But somehow im getting a black screen without any error. Why? the debug print statements are working...

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

//User logged in?
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final User? user = auth.currentUser;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
      if (user == null) {
        print('User is currently signed out!');
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SignIn());
      } else {
        String myUid = user.uid;
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen(userId: myUid));
        print('User is signed in!');
      }
    });
    return const SizedBox.shrink(); //<-----here
  }
}
```

Well my Code looking now like this:

```
    Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

//User logged in?
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

//The stream for auth changee
Future<User?> data() async {
  return FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
}

final User? user = auth.currentUser;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance
            .authStateChanges(), //FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('Something went wrong');
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Text("Loading");
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            if (user == null) {
              print('User is currently signed out!');
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SignIn()));
            } else {
              String myUid = user!.uid;
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => HomeScreen(
                            userId: myUid,
                          )));
            }
          }
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        });
  }
}
```

Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
The relevant error-causing widget was
StreamBuilder<User?>

Answer (score 0):

You can't just insert a stream listener in the `build` method like that. The easiest way to do this, is to use a `StreamBuilder` which handles the stream for you. Similar to the example in the documentation on [listening for Firestore updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#dart) that'd be something like:

```
StreamBuilder<User?>(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User?> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return const Text('Something went wrong');
    }

    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const Text("Loading");
    }

    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SignIn());
    } else {
      String myUid = user.uid;
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen(userId: myUid));
    }
  },
```

Comment: well, this is not working also. Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.

Comment: Sorry to hear that M.Nasiri. Does it make sense from my explanation why you need a `StreamBuilder` though? Also: that error message seems to have been covered before, so did you have a look at [those](https://www.google.com/search?q=navigator+operation+requested+with+a+context+that+does+not+include+a+navigator)?

Comment: there is a problem with the StreamBuilder<User?>

Comment: I don't think so, but only you can tell for sure. If you return a simple `Text("user")` instead of the `MaterialPageRoute`, does the error disappear?

Comment: if I just debug with a simple text, its working so then the problem is MaterialPageRoute...